# javascript setInterval() not firing on timer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm just working on this simple clock as a learning project

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var da = document.getElementById("display_area");

    function setClockDisplay()
    {
        var time = new Date();
        var hour = time.getHours();
        var minute = time.getMinutes();
        var second = time.getSeconds();

        var currentTime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

        da.innerHTML = currentTime;
    }

        setInterval(setClockDisplay(), 1000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="display_area"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

when I go to the page it displays the timestamp from when the page is originally loaded, but does not update every second like I would think. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
setInterval(setClockDisplay, 1000);
```

instead. [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) expects a function reference (you were invoking the function before).

**Updated code:** http://jsfiddle.net/VvG3k/

Comment: it works, thanks so much. I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me! :D